# IronPython and IronRuby vs Javascript in VS2010

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, ironpython, ironruby

I am very intrigued with python and ruby for scripting languages.
I am using the visual studio IDE and am gearing towards javascript for my scripting in web based applications, namely databasing sites with SQL, 
It seems JS is used alot and is admired but like to hear what ruby and python users have to say about their use for web apps especially in the VS2010 IDE, (IronRuby)(IronPython)..... ease of use, learning, and range of functionality compared to JS.